# Basic implode foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, implode

I have the following code of which I want to echo array elements separated by commas. The code outputs the disered list, but without commas. What am I missing?

```
<?php 
    $array    = get_field('casts');
    $elements = $array;

    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        echo implode(', ', $value)};
?>
```

**EDIT 1:** where `$elements` are nested arrays.

**EDIT 2:** Working snippet:

```php
<?php 
    $array = get_field('casts');
    $new_array = array();
    foreach($array as $sub_array) {
        foreach($sub_array as $value) { 
            array_push($new_array, $value);
        }
    }
    echo implode(", ", $new_array);
?>
```

Comment: If the `$value` contains only 1 element, `implode()` won't have any effect whatsoever.

Comment: Can you post a `var_dump` of $array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you assigning `$elements = $array;` and then never using `$elements`?

Also you don't need to loop (`foreach`) to implode an array.

Try this:

```
<?php
$array = get_field('casts');
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $sub_array) {
    foreach($sub_array as $value) {
        // this array_push() function adds $value to the end of $new_array.
        array_push($new_array, $value);
    }
}
echo implode(", ", $new_array);
?>
```

Here is the documentation on [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

You can play around and test the above code [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rhmBjk).

Also next time, add the tag `php`, otherwise our codes won't get color syntax.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that $elements are nested arrays. Your answer gives me Array,Array,Array...

Comment: @elbatron Could you do `print_r($array);` and tell me the output in your (edited) question? Knowing the actual value of `$array` will help me understand your problem better. If it's too long, then just give me the first few elements. Thanks.

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [actor] => Natalie Portman ) [1] => Array ( [actor] => Vincent Cassel ) [2] => Array ( [actor] => Mila Kunis ))

Comment: Well I'm not sure why you have an array containing many 1-element arrays. But I think my edited answer works for you. In the future why not just do something simple like `$actors = new Array("Natalie Portman", "Vincent Cassel", "Mila Kunis")`?

Comment: I'm assuming he has other information other than just the name.  That is each "actor array" contains information such as age, DoB, etc.

Comment: So does he want a separate list for actors, age, DoB? My current solution will mash up all the sub-arrays into a one-dimensional array, then implode it.

Comment: Lol sorry I forgot a `;` in the line for `array_push(...)`

Comment: @elbatron Remove the `new` keyword. That should fix the problem.

Comment: @Jack, I have no other information just name. I'm working with a loop module and not able to change the way it works.

Comment: @KemalFadillah Sorry, I was using JavaScript syntax. I just tested the code on a PHP interpreter so everything should be fine now.